# Plot[Zeta[x], {x, 2, 20}, ScalingFunctions -> "Log"] is not logarithmic

Tags: plotting, special-functions, logarithmic-scale

The code

```
Plot[Zeta[x], {x, 2, 20}, ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]
```

produces the following image, which is a plot of the `Zeta` function but the `y`-axis is not logarithmic.

[image: Plot of Zeta-function]

Replacing `Zeta` by a different function produces a logarithmic scaling on the `y`-axis.

The scaling function `Log10` and `Log2` also fail.
`LogPlot` also fails.

I tested the code in 12.2 and 11.3, both fail.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?
I'm hesitating to call this a bug (and report it to Wolfram), as this seems to be something which should have been encountered before.

Comment: Log scaling of the range $[1.00, 1.08]$ is going to appear nearly linear.

Comment: To convince yourself that the log scaling is happening, enlarge the ordinate range: `Plot[Zeta[x], {x, 2, 20}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0.1, 10}}, ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]`.

Comment: Ahh, you are both right. I knew this is not a bug and I am missing something. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe worth showing this:
Verification of log scaling, although with a significant but small error in the first point:

```
plot = Plot[Zeta[x], {x, 2, 20}, ScalingFunctions -> "Log"];

{xvals, logzvals} = 
  Transpose@First@Cases[plot, Line[p_] :> p, Infinity];

Rest@Log@Zeta[xvals] == Rest@logzvals
(* True  *)

First@Log@Zeta[xvals] - First@logzvals
(*  -0.0000556227  *)
```

(Log scaling of the small range $[1.00,1.08]$ is going to appear nearly linear. In fact, any scaling by an analytic function over a small enough range will appear linear.)

Comment: Anyone have an explanation for the error in the first point?  Seems too big not to be a bug, but it's small enough not to make a different to the picture.  I go so far as to suggest a bug, since sometimes people use the output of `Plot` for numerical computations.  (There's an error without the log scaling, too.)

Comment: It seems to be somehow linked with the automatically restricted plot range. Adding `PlotRange -> All`  to the `plot` expression removes the error (i.e. your last expression evaluates to $0$). I don't understand why it happened in the first place though.

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks. It seems to happen with other functions and truncated plot ranges, with varying degrees of error.

Comment: @MarcoB Perhaps the endpoint of the truncated plot is done by simpliy cutting the first/last line segment (in effect, using linear interpolation).  It would be simpler than solving `y == f[x]` for the boundary point.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a bug. Just the scale is small enough to be noticed by the eye!

You can try this code, which is just your code added a more length of the y-axis :

```
Plot[Zeta[x], {x, 2, 20}, ScalingFunctions -> "Log", 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {0, 2}}]
```

Now the result is :

[image: plot]

in which the logarithmic scale is more emphasized.